# Creating a dynamic/complex Android viewText + editText layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view, textview

I'd like to do something a little complex for my android application, and I'm struggling a little.

**Overview** -

I'm creating a game where the player is given a sentence with some words blanked out, and they must fill in the gaps.

> '22 P____ on a F____ P____' becomes '22 Players on a Football Pitch'
>
> 'J_____ B_____ is 007' - 'James Bond is 007',

and so forth.

I'm having trouble laying out the `textViews + editText's` in a way that I like. Their are lots, and lots of these questions - so many that I don't want to hand code a solution.

I want to dynamically create the `textViews + the editViews` - from the question I pass it. I can create them just fine, it's the adding to the final view I am struggling with - all of the items are bunched into one corner! A `linearLayout` changes that, but then it's a single element on each line.

I've tried looking online - but I'm not convinced I'm looking at any of the right materials.

**What I want is to create something exactly like the picture below (sorry it's so huge)** - I think I want to create a wrapper of sorts for all the separate elements (so it lays out nicely) or a make my own custom view class(?) - but I really am unsure of how to progress - so any advice would be great.

Thank you

[image: Ideal solution image]

Comment: Extend `View` to create a simulated combo view, that is all I can point you towards, how to do it? search developer.android.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation where I wanted to have a list of names that would go side-to-side if possible, but if a name was long to begin on the next line.

I played around with a library called [android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout). It has good examples and is fairly easy to customize.

Comment: I er, just wanted to let you know that, I er, kinda love you a little bit right now. Actually maybe even more than a little bit.